# How to fetch value of Dataslots in custom Jsp in Savvion BPM?

Tags: business-process-management

I am using Progress Savvion BPM Studio 8.0.
I want to use value of "Dataslot" (variable) in custom jsp page with Scriptlet.
I am getting value of some "Dataslot" from previous activity and now I want to perform some action on that "Dataslot" and display it in table. But I don't know how to get/use value of "Dataslot" inside scriptlet.
I should use `request.getParameter()` or `jst.getDataSlotValue()`.
I tried both of them but I am not getting any error or output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it from `bean.getProp(String,Object,Boolean)` based on the type of the dataslot in the JSP. You also need to add the dataslot as input to the BizSolo or Custom JSP you have added in the bizlogic process.

Also you need to define bean with `com.savvion.BizSolo.beans.Bean` and with scope as Session.